# Excel VBA - out of memory error (runtime 7)

Tags: excel, vba, lotus-notes

I am getting a very weird error when using VBA in excel. I am using LotusNotes Automation libraries to loop through a view and write everything to cell.

Here is my code (variables of non-interest are removed as I know they are not causing the problem)

Public Function TimeCh()

```
Set session = New NotesSession 'create a new session (ask for user/pass)
session.Initialize             'initialize the session (allow login)
Set db = session.GetDatabase("HIDDEN") 'Grab the DB
Set view = db.GetView("HIDDEN") 'Get the view




Application.ScreenUpdating = False


'start the loop to go through data
While Not (entry Is Nothing)
    Cells(row, 1) = (entry.ColumnValues(4))
    Cells(row, 2) = (entry.ColumnValues(0))
    Cells(row, 3) = (entry.ColumnValues(26))
    Cells(row, 4) = (entry.ColumnValues(27))
    Cells(row, 5) = (entry.ColumnValues(22))
    Cells(row, 6) = (entry.ColumnValues(20))
    Cells(row, 7) = (entry.ColumnValues(29))
    Cells(row, 8) = (entry.ColumnValues(31))
    Cells(row, 9) = (entry.ColumnValues(30))
    Cells(row, 10) = (entry.ColumnValues(8))
    Cells(row, 11) = (entry.ColumnValues(7))
    Cells(row, 12) = (entry.ColumnValues(21))
    Cells(row, 13) = (entry.ColumnValues(19))
    Cells(row, 14) = (entry.ColumnValues(24))
    Cells(row, 15) = (entry.ColumnValues(25))
    Cells(row, 16) = (entry.ColumnValues(32))
    Cells(row, 17) = (entry.ColumnValues(28))
    Cells(row, 18) = (entry.ColumnValues(9))
    Cells(row, 19) = (entry.ColumnValues(12))
    Cells(row, 20) = (entry.ColumnValues(11))
    Cells(row, 21) = (entry.ColumnValues(23))
    Cells(row, 22) = (entry.ColumnValues(10))
    Cells(row, 23) = (entry.ColumnValues(2))
    Cells(row, 24) = (entry.ColumnValues(33))
    Cells(row, 25) = (entry.ColumnValues(1))
    Cells(row, 26) = (entry.ColumnValues(13))
    Cells(row, 27) = (entry.ColumnValues(5))
    Cells(row, 28) = (entry.ColumnValues(14))
    Cells(row, 29) = (entry.ColumnValues(6))
    Cells(row, 30) = (entry.ColumnValues(18))
    Cells(row, 31) = (entry.ColumnValues(16))
    Cells(row, 32) = (entry.ColumnValues(3))
    Cells(row, 33) = (entry.ColumnValues(15))
    Cells(row, 34) = (entry.ColumnValues(17))
    Cells(row, 35) = (entry.ColumnValues(34))
    row = row + 1
    Set entry = vec.GetNextEntry(entry)
Wend
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Function

So it **ALWAYS** fails on when row = 1425 and column is 35. It gives a "out of memory" (runtime 7 error). It cant be a hardware thing because the system is very stable (dual core, 2 gig ram). And it  always crashes at the same row.

I did a search,and  I found one relevant thread:
["Out of Memory" error in Lotus Notes automation from VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2721654/out-of-memory-error-in-lotus-notes-automation-from-vba)

Has anyone seen something like this before?

Comment: I may regret this, but can you show the entire procedure?

Comment: That is the entire code. Unless you wanna see variables defined (ie, dim statements)

Comment: Actually, yes. I was hoping for variable definitions as well as the Sub and End Sub lines so we can see which variables are internal and external.  I don't have any solutions in mind when I write this, but it could be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the company install Excel 2007 on my computer. Ran the report with no problems at all, so I guess it must be a 2003 internal bug.

Answer (score 1):

If the code is consistently failing on the same document and the same column in the view, that would lead me to believe there is some data issue with that one document. Can you trap the error and show some unique identifier for the failing document? I would try to do that, and then look in the 35th column of the view for that document and check the value. Perhaps there is a computation in the view column which is returning @Error or similar - and in turn causing the VBA code to throw the memory exception.

Comment: I had the company install Excel 2007 on my computer. Ran the report with no problems at all, so I guess it must be a 2003 internal bug.

Comment: Ed has a point. Can you verify that the document data is valid?

Answer (score 0):

Random questions:

1. What data type is row? If you define row as a double, does it still crash?
2. Per the link you quoted (thanks, actually. It was my post), if you define session as a static variable, does it still crash?
3. Even if you don't do #2, do you remember to close your session by the end of the function?
4. This looks like just a subset of a much larger function.  How many times is it called in a row?

Comment: 1)It is a string. 
2)It is not static, but i will try it.
3)Dosn't even reach the end of the function. 
4)It loops through all the documents, about 6000 of them.

Comment: I had the company install Excel 2007 on my computer. Ran the report with no problems at all, so I guess it must be a 2003 internal bug.